# Springboot how to redirect parent page in fragment(thymeleaf) when session destroyed

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a page need to redirect to parent page in the thymeleaf.

I click the nextPageDiv want to change full page when the session is destroyed.

So I create the class to implement HandlerInterceptor.

part code below:

```
@Component
public class MySessionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
 
  ...

 @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(); 
        if (session.isNew()) {
            response.sendRedirect("login");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
 
    }

  ...
}
```

My html construct is below:

[image]

But the result is click the nextPageDiv, the page just change containerList part.

Not change all fullPage to login page.

How can I redirect the full page in the thymeleaf  in the fragment?

Thanks

Comment: If you are doing an ajax call/xmlhttprequest you need to handle that yourself on the client (and replace the whole page).

Comment: So we can't relay springboot HandlerInterceptor session timeout mechanism to redirect the all page when I using ajax?thnsks.

Comment: You could if you have a generic handler on the client side.